# Unity3D mouse cursor visibility - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cursor, mouse, visibility

I want to set cursor invisible and locked on the middle of the screen when the game is running, but when in inventory or in menu I want cursor visible and unlocked. I made something like that:

```
if (tribe == game) {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        } else if (tribe == menu) {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else if (tribe == inventory) {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
```

Conditions are made properly and work (unless I should call it in every frame), but lock states and visibility is bugged. Sometimes it works, sometimes not (maybe it's caused by the fact I run it in Unity Editor) and it's behave weird.
Should I call it every frame or I use it wrong or something?

Comment: Try calling it every frame? Maybe your code somewhere else is setting the Cursor lock state? Have you tried logging the state of Cursor.lockState, etc. every frame?

Comment: I called it everyframe and didn't work too. But I perceive something wrong - menu didn't paused my game properly. Maybe error is here, but I don't think so, so if someone know how to solve that please answer.

Comment: Do you check if statements? I think put log in statements to see it app reach it properly.

Comment: I put print () in one of the if statements and it printed what I wanted but cursor visibility don't work how it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your update loop be throwing an error that isn't caught and preventing your logic from running?  We saw a few issues where errors were happening but not showing up in the console, we put a try catch around the whole update block and narrowed things down from there.

Comment: I think it's impossible. I tested that a lot of time and it's not error. The only problem what can be here is my fault somewhere, but it's only script when I use that so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

All of the cursor stuff must happen in the "OnGUI" method of your script.
Ex:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    Cursor.visible = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}
```